# Can you embed a whole webpage into c++ source?

Tags: c++, reactjs, embedded-resource

Is there an equivalent to [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) for c++ that can embed a react app into c++ source so it can be compiled into the binary? I know things like xxd can embed a single file into a c array, but I need something that works on multiple files and preserves paths and whatnot for use with an embedded htttp server.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but there are a lot of people more experienced than I, so maybe.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to compile reactjs to a single html file so `xxd -i` will be sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about reactjs. I came from the C++ tag. Probably, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a more efficient alternative to xxd -i [(here)](https://github.com/dvhar/csvquery/blob/master/deps/mbin2c.c) and a shell script that uses it [(here)](https://github.com/dvhar/csvquery/blob/master/deps/embed.sh) that generate a header included in the server source file [here](https://github.com/dvhar/csvquery/blob/master/server.cc), and it works great. The c program is extremely unpolished and the script is specific to my directory structure (which is not commited to github right now), but this solution could easily be adapted for other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can embed anything into a binary. The limit is normally just being reasonable (if you go over 100 MB you should start considering if what you are doing is a good idea).

You may want to look into the proposed [`std::embed` (P1040)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1040r4.html) for ideas.